# How do I know if PC is connected to my turtlebot?

Tags: slam, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason, we think the opencr board on out turtlebot3 was damaged and motors are not working, so teleop is not an option. I tried to setup the remote PC. I followed exactly http://turtlebot3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bringup.html
When I typed in

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot3_slam`/rviz/turtlebot3_slam.rviz
```

I got this:

[image: image description]

I don't think this was what supposed to look like. Because in the simulator, before I got the robot I used the simulator. Once I start slam, it will show the current surround even without moving teleop. I don't think the robot is correctly connected to my pc, so the RVis is just running on its own.

How do I exactly know if the robot is "connected" to my pc (without using teleop)?
Or maybe I am wrong, this is what supposed to happen.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267539/how-do-i-know-if-pc-is-connected-to-my-turtlebot?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the comments replying to @Marq if you only see `/rosout` and `/rosout_agg` you're likely connecting to a `rosmaster`  that is standalone and not on the robot.

You will need to return to your network settings and validate everything in your bringup to make sure you substitude the right values for the robot and workstation IPs.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1